# Graph and PRIM and DIJKSTRA Problems?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, dijkstra, shortest-path

We are given an Undirected, Weighted and Connected Graph G, (without negative weight and all weights are distinct) that shortest path between *any* two vertexes on this graph is on minimum spanning tree. 
Then:

> I) Graph G is a Tree.
>
> II) weight of each {u,v} edge, is at least equal to heaviest edge in
>   shortest path from u to v.
>
> III) shortest path between any two vertex u, v is unique.
>
> IV) suppose start from vertex `s`, Prime (for calculating MST) and Dijkstra (for calculating shortest path), process and add the
>   vertexes into a Tree, with the same order. (two algorithm works with same order in processing and adding node)

Please explain, why just two of these claims is TRUE? I am confusing with the definition, Proposed by OUR TA.

Comment: "We know the shortest path between any two vertexes is on minimum spanning tree." I doubt that this is correct. Have a graph with nodes a,b and c. Edges a to c and b to c have weight 1 and 1.1. Edge from a to b has weight 1.5. Then the shortest path from a to b is not on the minimum spanning tree.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker, if we suppose the integer, is it okey ?

Comment: @SpaceTrucker Maybe I am wrong, but I think, this question is asking what is the correct condition **if** all shortest paths are on its minimum spanning tree. So this is not a general, but asking about a special case.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker Apparently, this statement is not a claim, but a requirement.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it should be migrated to http://cs.stackexchange.com/ as it's not related to a coding issue.

Comment: @HouraAsali Please see the comments below; apparently there is some misunderstanding on the requirement about shortest paths being contained in a minimum spanning tree. Is it possible to edit the question for more clarity? Is it supposed to be "there is a minimum spanning tree T such that for each pair of nodes A and B, there is a shortest path p between A and B which is contained in T" or is it supposed to be "for every pair of nodes A and B, for every shortest path p between A and B, there is a minimum spanning tree T which contains p", or is it something different?

Comment: @Codor, thanks please read it now, is it okey?

Comment: The minimum spanning tree still is not quatified. Is is required to exist? Should someting hold for *all* minimum spanning trees?

Comment: @Codor, we know in a Graph G(without negative weights, with distinct weight, connected, undirected)‌ the shortest path between any of two vertexes is place on MST. It means (I‌ Think) are holds for all MST on this graph.

Comment: @HouraAsali This is not the case, as can be seen in the graph given by ysrhung below.

Comment: @Codor, please add it to your answer with defining requirement to accept and bounty it...

Comment: I‌ Think we must consider just example that shortest path between any of tow vertex that on MST. @Codor.

Comment: @Codor, I‌ got it. we must consider all shortest path between two vertex is on MST.

Answer (score 1):

Let `G=(V,E,w)` be a weighted graph with the following properties.

1. `w(e)>=0` for each `e in E` and `w(e1) != w(e2)` for each `e1,e2 in E` with `e1 != e2`.
2. For each `a,b in V`, for each shortest path `p` from `a` to `b` in `G` there exists a minimum spanning tree `T` of `G` such that `p` is contained in `T`.

*Note that property 2 is not stated totally clearly in the requirement, but to my understanding, this is what is meant by the OP, since other interpretations don't actually make sense: if for any pair of vertices `a` and `b`, there are two shortest paths `p1` and `p2` between them, they cannot be contained in the same minimum spanning tree, as they would form a cycle. Likewise, given a shortest path `p` between `a` and `b`, there does not necessarily exist a minimum spanning tree which contains `p`.*

Then, statements I) and IV) are not necessarily true, but statements II) and III) are true.

For statement I), consider the following counterexample. Let `G:=(V,E,w)` with `V:={1,2,3}`, `E:={{1,2},{1,3},{2,3}}` and

```
w({1,2}):=1,
w({1,3}):=2,
w({2,3}):=4.
```

Note that all edge weights are positive and distinct, hence property 1 from above is satisfied. Furthermore, the edges `{1,2}` and `{1,3}` constitute the only minimum spanning tree `T` for `G`.  Finally, the only shortest path from `1` to `2` is `{1,2}`, the only shortest path from `1` to `3` is `{1,3}`, and the only shortest path from `2` to `3` is `{2,1}{1,3}`. All of these paths are included in `T`. However, `G` contains the cycle `{1,2},{2,3},{3,1}`, hence it is not a tree.

For statement II), let `u,v in V`. Let `p` be a shortest path from `u` to `v` in `G`. Assume that `w({u,v})` is smaller than an edge of maximum weight in `p`. Then `{u,v}` is a path from `u` to `v` in `G` with weight smaller than the total weight of `p`, which must be larger than `w({u,v})` as all edge weights are positive. This means that `p` is not a shortest path from `u` to `v` in `G`, a contradiction.

For statement III), note that the minimum spanning tree is uniquely determined; this follows from the workings of the algorithm of Prim, as the distinct edge weights from property 1 from above make the choice of the lightest edge deterministic. Alternatively, this can be seen inductively by arguing that each spanning tree must contain an edge of minimum weight of `G`. In total, as the minimum spanning tree `T` is uniquely determined, there can be only one shortest path from `u` to `v` in `G` for each `u,v in V`, as each shortest path must be contained in `T`. If two such paths existed, `T` had a cycle, which is not the case.

For statement IV), consider the following counterexample. Let `G:=(V,E,w)` where `V:={1,2,3,4}`, `E:={{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{2,4},{3,4}}` and

```
w({1,2}):=01,
w({1,3}):=04,
w({2,3}):=10,
w({2,4}):=03,
w({3,4}):=09.
```

Suppose [Prim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) and [Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Algorithm) start at node `1`. Then, the edges `{1,2},{2,3},{3,4}` consitute the uniquely determined minimum spanning tree `T`, which is generated by Prim in the sequence `1,2,4,3`.

The path `{1,2}` is the only shortest path from `1` to `2`, `{1,3}` is the only shortest path from `1` to `3`; `{1,2}{2,4}` is the only shortest path from `1` to `4` and `{4,2}{2,1}{1,3}` is the only shortest path from `4` to `3`. Furthermore, `{2,3}` is the only shortest path from `2` to `3` and `{2,1}{1,4}` is the only shortest path from `2` to `4`. In total, `G` has properties 1 and 2 from above.

The choices of Dijkstra can be done as follows, where `++` denotes infinity.

```
Node                1  2  3  4
tentative distance 00 01 04 ++
discovered          y  n  n  n
=> select node 2

Node                1  2  3  4
tentative distance 00 01 04 04
discovered          y  y  n  n
=> select node 3 (could also select 4, as Prim, but selects 3)

Node                1  2  3  4
tentative distance 00 01 04 04
discovered          y  y  y  n
=> select node 4
```

In total, the sequence of selected nodes is `1,2,3,4`, which differs from the sequence generated by Prim.

Comment: Does this exhaustively answer the question? Did I understand the requirement about the shortest paths being contained in an minimum spanning tree right or is it to be understood differently?

Comment: +1, Nice answer. I think You need to consider two case for III case when this is false and case when this is true, to get high vote up. I think this is the reason for not attention your nice answer by others. inspect of this view, please complete for III.

Comment: Thanks for the comment; what exactly do you mean by "this"? This shortest-path-being-contained-in-the-minimum-spanning-tree-thing which puzzles me?

Comment: we have two case in III.  if we consider Any shortest path must be on MST The statement is True, if consider there exists a shortest path on MST this is false. am I right?

Comment: @user4249446 I think this greatly depends on the sequence of quantifiers. Is it supposed to be "there is a minimum spanning tree T such that for each pair of nodes A and B, there is a shortest path p between A and B which is contained in T" or is it supposed to be "for every pair of nodes A and B, for every shortest path p between A and B, there is a minimum spanning tree T which contains p", or is it something different?

Comment: your trace on Dijkstra has lots of typo.

Comment: your trace on Dijkstra has lots of typo.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I can't spot them.

Comment: Select node 3 in step 2 and in step 3 again select node 3?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by : "could also select 4, as Prim, but selects 3" if select 4 both algorithm works same. !!!

Comment: Yes, exactly. But if 3 is selected, the algorithms perform differently. There is no tie-breaking rule for Dijsktra which node with minimmum tentative distance is to be selected.

Comment: am I Right with this statements? Consider this tree: V = {1, 2, 3, 4}, E = {(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 2), (1, 4, 4)}. Let's assume that the start vertex is 1. Prim's algorithm will take the first vertex, than the second one, than the third one and only after this the fourth. But Dijkstra's algorithm will take the fourth vertex before the third one. It happens because the third vertex is located closer to the tree after processing the first two vertices, but it the total distance to it from the start node is larger.

Comment: @user4249446 The example seems to be valid.

Comment: In your example, the single edge DA is not a spanning tree.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I think so.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Codor that Statement I is not necessarily true and Statement II is true. Codor's proof for Statements I and II are correct. However, I think that Statement III and not necessarily true and Statement IV is true.

For Statement III, there is a counter example: 
There are 3 vertices A, B and C. There are 3 edges (A, B), (B, C) and (A, C) whose weights are 1, 2 and 3 respectively. The minimum spanning tree includes the edges (A, B) and (B, C). However, shortest path between A and C is not unique: either (i) (A, B), (B, C), or (ii) (A, C)

Statement IV is correct. This could be proved by mathematical induction.

Comment: Concerning Statement III, your graph is *not* a counterexample. Indeed, there are two shortest paths between A and C, both of weight 3, but there is no minimum spanning tree which includes the path (A,C), as required - the mentioned spanning tree is the *only* spanning tree.

Comment: Statement III,claims that "shortest path between any two vertex u, v is unique." In my example, it shows a graph in which shortest path between two vertices A and C is NOT unique (there are two shortest path). Also, the graph fulfills the requirement that "shortest path between any two vertexes is on minimum spanning tree. ". Therefore, this counterexample shows statement III is not always true.

Comment: Exactly the last point in your comment is not valid. The shortest path (A,C) is *not* contained in a minimum spanning tree.

Comment: First of all, in the statement "given an Undirected, Weighted and Connected Graph G, (without negative weight and all weights are distinct) in which the shortest path between any two vertexes is on minimum spanning tree. ", it requires the graph to have shortest path between any two vertices is on minimum spanning tree. This does not imply ALL shortest paths between any two vertices must be on the minimum spanning tree. (Please note that if the minimum spanning tree contains edges of two shortest path, then it's no longer a minimum spanning tree)....

Comment: Second, in my example, there are two shortest paths between A and C where one of them is on the minimum spanning tree (i.e. (A, B) and (B, C)). Therefore, this is a valid counter example according to the definition of the problem.

Comment: I totally get your point, but I believe the requirement to be understood as "for every pair of nodes A and B, for every shortest path p between A and B, there exists a minimum spanning tree which contains p."